# Editable table view cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, input, uitableview

I am creating an application. I have to implement a bookmark feature, and adding one should be similar to this:

[mmm http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/9859/schermafbeelding2010040a.png](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/9859/schermafbeelding2010040a.png)

I want editable `UITableViewCell`s for text input. I was wondering if there is an easier way then embedding a `UITextField` into a `UITableViewCell`. And if not, can someone explain how I can use the `UITextField` inside it? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't an easier way, you will have to subclass UITableViewCell and add in the UITextField.  Here is a tutorial for [using a UITextView](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-using-a-uitableviewcell-with-a-uitextview-for-entering-text-part-1-of-2/)  should be about the same as a UITextField.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a textfield to the contentView of your cell, and an (X) button to the accessoryView of your cell. You could do that in a UITableView subclass which would let you add keep track of your added elements with instance variables or properties.

I found this helpful: [Cocoa With Love: Easy custom UITableView drawing](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)

Like this:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                              reuseIdentifier:@"myEditableCellId"];
label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog for simple cases like that. But you probably need to write your own custom cell if it's more complex.